# Why is thread_local variable never initialised here?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am working my way through [C++ Crash Course](https://nostarch.com/cppcrashcourse) where I have encountered the following code listing:

```
#include <cstdio>

struct Tracer {
  Tracer(const char* name)
      : name{ name } {
    printf("%s constructed.\n", name);
  }
  ~Tracer() {
    printf("%s destructed.\n", name);
  }

  private:
  const char* const name;
};

static Tracer t1{ "Static variable" };
thread_local Tracer t2{ "Thread-local variable" };

int main() {
  printf("A\n");
  Tracer t3{ "Automatic variable" };
  printf("B\n");
  const auto* t4 = new Tracer{ "Dynamic variable" };
  printf("C\n");
}
```

The author of the book claims that I am supposed to see:

```
Static variable constructed.
Thread-local variable constructed.
A 
Automatic variable constructed.
B
Dynamic variable constructed.
C
Automatic variable destructed.
Thread-local variable destructed.
Static variable destructed.
```

Which makes perfect sense for me. However, when I run this on my machine (MacOS, CLion, g++) I see the following:

```
Static variable constructed.
A
Automatic variable constructed.
B
Dynamic variable constructed.
C
Automatic variable destructed.
Static variable destructed.
```

Why is the behaviour different and what happens to the `t2` variable?

Comment: A bit of opinionated feedback: if a C++ course insists on teaching things like `const char*`, `printf(`  `<cstdio>` and even `new`, then, perhaps it is time to look for alternative C++ course.

Comment: Noted, I have already read "A Tour of C++" and I was looking for something modern, but slightly more verbose. This piece of code is meant to illustrate different lifetimes. Any good recommendation for additional books?

Comment: Further opinionated feedback: the header `<cstdio>` is required to put names like `printf` in the namespace `std`, and is **allowed** to put those names in the global namespace. So calls to `printf` should use the namespace prefix, i.e., `std::printf`. Without it, the code **might** compile (and if it does it will run correctly), but it is not required to. So this code is simply wrong. I agree with @Ron -- look for an alternative C++ course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `thread_local` variable can be initialized when the thread starts but can also be initialized only when it's used (the standard mandates that it will be initialized before its first use). The guarantee is also that, if initialized, it will be destroyed when the thread terminates.

Comment: Ok, so that means that there are no guarantees for an eager initialisation here despite the book hinting at that? But if the initialisation does happen, it is guaranteed to be cleaned up correctly.

Comment: reference - C++17 [basic.start.dynamic]/6 . Also there is a guarantee that if one thread_local in that TU is odr-used then all of them are initialized.

Comment: and this is implementation-defined, i.e. the compiler's documentation should describe when and how it defers the initialization